# What do I need to change to my web page responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make my page responsive. Irrespective of screen size,my content should align both vertically and horizontally and there will be some margin between my edge of browser and the content.

fiddle link: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1bLsvun/)

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}
.parent {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.centered-content {
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0 auto;
}
p {
 font-family: Lato;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: white;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 640px;

}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .default {
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .centered-content {
    width: 640px;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .centered-content {
    width: 520px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .centered-content {
    width: 272px;
  }
  p .default {
    max-width: 272px;
    margin-top: 48px;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
}
```

```html
div class="parent">
 <div class="centered-content">
       <p class="default">
         Hey, I'm lorem.
         <br><br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         <br><br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
       </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please provide fiddle link.

Comment: Edit your question, then add the link properly. And add the codes in the question too

Comment: Thanks PurpleSoft for editing. Sorry guys, I was completely new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

User @media query in your `CSS` here the media query size

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: As this is a possibility indeed, seeming that the OP is having trouble making his/her webpage responsive aswell. Why don't we get him/her to try out bootstrap for responsiveness

Comment: I am using media query but can't find a way

Comment: Better you use `Bootstrap` here the link:http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear. My 2 cents is that you should use bootstrap or any other responsive framework to help you in your quest to responsiveness.
http://getbootstrap.com

Read the docs and learn about the grid system

Happy Programming!

Comment: I added bootstrap too. But nothing happens . You can see my code snippet. Thanks to PurpleSoft.